# Defining macro to see the pin directions

Tags: c++, c, arduino, avr

In avr or arduino, I need to pass port name to a function, which must use a macro like:

```
#define setDDR(a) (DDR ## a)
```

to see the pin directions. What I am trying to do is like:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    pinMode(13,OUTPUT);

    printToScreen(B);
}

void loop() {

}

#define setDDR(a) (DDR ## a)

void printToScreen(uint8_t i)
{
    Serial.println(setDDR(i),BIN);
}
```

But this code gives me a error like " 'B' was not declared in this scope ".

Comment: Macros are basically a simple query-replace mechanism that happens at *compile time*. That means all arguments will be evaluated at compile-time, and you can't use run-time variables like you do.

Comment: On a side-note, Arduino are programmed in C++ not C.

Comment: Macros are expanded at *compile* time.  They operate on syntactic units ("tokens") of *source code*, not on runtime values.  Thus, your macro invocation `setDDR(i)` expands to `DDRi`, which is not useful to you.  At minimum, it does not distinguish between different runtime values of the `i` function parameter.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Not necessarily. The wonky C++ variant is for people who rely on bloated, slow, crappy, and incompatible libraries.  I regularly program all manner of Arduinos in C and program with either JTAG or ISP.

Comment: OP should read the documentation for the part.  Then OP will realize that "PORT B" is really a convenience, itself only a macro.

Answer (score 1):

```c
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    pinMode(13,OUTPUT);

    printToScreen(setDDR(B));
}
```

You cant input **B** to **printToScreen** since it's not a macro.

Comment: Well I guess that's the only solution if he wants to keep it as a function, but I think using it like this makes the macro useless because it doesn't really improve readability and it's just more work to writting 'setDDR(B)' instead of 'DDRB'

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are passing it into a function, not a macro, this means it assumes that B is a variable, just rewrite *"printToScreen"* into a macro:

```
#define printToScreen(port) Serial.println(DDR # port, BIN)
```

Comment: But what if I use a new class and its constructor function than create an instance like;

newClass.cpp
```
#include "newClass.h"

#define setDDR(a) (DDR ## a)

// default constructor
newClass::newClass(uint8_t port)
{
 Serial.println(setDDR(port));
} 
```
mainClass.cpp
```
newClass inst1(B);
```

My aim is adjusting the pins to output/input by creating instance with port number and bit 
```
newClass btn1(B,1)
```

Comment: well you can't use macro inside of function with its parameters, macros expand before compilation and variables get filled during runtime, it'll take the macro input and literally replace itself(the macro) with its code and parameters, hence setDDR(port) => DDR ## port => DDRport

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in the comments, you cannot use macros at run time.

But you can use other approaches. For example, you can pass a pointer to an IO-port. E.g.

```
void printToScreen(volatile uint8_t * p)
{
    Serial.println(*p, BIN);
}

...

printToScreen(&PORTB);
```